# What port does webRTC use?

Tags: tcp, webrtc, p2p

if when i try to connect with webRTC from outside the local network, it uses a STUN server to exchange info like ip address, port..., and then once the two clients know each other they will directly connect, but the thing is, if any router by default blocks any port that's opened exept for 80, then how do the two clients connect, on what port?

Comment: The stun server is not used to exchange information like ip address and port. That is the signalling server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebRTC is an open framework and does not dictate how the connections are established between the communicating peers. Establishing the connection itself involves the following.

1-The peer discovery is made via Signaling for doing SDP exchanges and exchanging remote host identities. The Signaling can be done over any transport – UDP/TCP, any protocol and via any standard (SIP/XMPP) or custom application level protocol over HTTP/WebSockets etc. The choice of Ports for signalling traffic is left open to the application developer.

2-Once the peer discovery is complete, and the PeerConnections are established at each endpoints, the media data can be sent. Depending on the network topology of the Peers (whether they are in the same host network, or they are in different network (behind Nated IP address), they can choose to connect such that the media traffic is sent over UDP or over TCP. For a more protected environment, the peers may even need a TURN server to relay the media traffic on Peers behalf. Here again, the choice of Media Ports is left open and can be decided via the end application.
I found this on web I hope its helpful